# java regex to match duplicate numbers and not 0 ,1

Tags: java, regex, match, digits

I need to write pattern that match 11 digits that start with 012 and two digits after 012 should not be 0,1 and should be repeated.
for example: 01244521478 is true or 01266235698 is true and 01200256354 is false. I tried this pattern: `"012(.)\\1{1}([\\d]{6}$)"` but I don't know where to say 0,1 not allowed after 012 .
help me please

Answer (score 1):

Your regex `012(.)\1{1}([\d]{6}$)` is fine but is not able to take care of your **4th and 5th digits should not be 0 or 1 and should be repeated** requirements. Also `{1}` is not needed as it is implicit by default. Use it only in case when value inside curley brackets is more than one or a range like this `{2}` or `{1,5}`

This regex should meet your needs,

```
^(?=\d{11}$)012([^01])\1\d{6}$
```

**Explanation:**

- `^` --> start of string
- `(?=\d{11}$)` --> Positive look ahead to ensure it contains only numbers and is exactly of 11 digits. Why this is needed because of `[^01]` to negate 0 and 1 but not to allow any other characters.
- `012` --> Matches 012 literally
- `([^01])\1` --> the next two digits will be repeated and can be anything except 0 and 1
- `\d{6}` --> Matches any six digits
- `$` --> End of input

**[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/zzvgVB/1)**

Answer (score 0):

In your regex you use `(.)\\1` which will capture any character in a group and refer to that caputure using a backreference which will for example also match `012$$521478`

What you could do is change `(.)\\1)` to match digits from 2 till 9 like `([2-9])\\1`. You could omit the second capturing group if you are not referring to that in your tool or code. The `{1}` can be omitted and `[\\d]` can be written as `\\d`

The updated regex could look like:

`^012([2-9])\1\d{6}$`

In Java:

```
String regex = "^012([2-9])\\1\\d{6}$";
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/BFByzZ/1) | [Java demo](https://ideone.com/uUxfnl)

**Explanation**

- `^` Assert the start of the string
- `012` match literally
- `([2-9])` Capture in a group a digit 2-9
- `\1` backreference to the first capturing group
- `\d{6}` match 6 digits
- `$` Assert the end of the string